# Make this silverlight popup modal?

Tags: vb.net, silverlight

I have a silverlight app that pops open a new window using this:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(New Uri(page_url, "_blank", "toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes")
```

But I would like this to be modal (the calling silverlight to wait for it to complete). I've found a few mentions about modal popups in Silverlight, but nothing that helped me with this problem. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You want the [ChildWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow(v=vs.95).aspx) class.

Comment: @Benjamin I would prefer to have something that opens in a new browser window all together. The silverlight app is hosted in just a part of an asp page, so people can still go click on other non-silverlight buttons, which I want to avoid.